# BST and 2-3-4 Tree heights

Tags: graph, binary-search-tree, 2-3-4-tree

I have the following problem:

> Suppose T1 is a binary search tree and T2 is a 2-3-4 tree and they
> have each been formed from the same number of keys S. Let H1 be the
> height of T1 and H2 be the height of T2.
>
> i. Briefly explain why H1 is
> less than or equal to H2 for any S
>
> ii. Describe the nature of T1 and
> T2 when H1 equals H2

But I don't understand, isn't it the other way around? Isn't the height of the binary search be greater than the one of the 2-3-4 tree?
For example if I have the following sequence of keys: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10 and I construct the trees:

Binary Search Tree:

[image]

2-3-4 Tree:

```
       4,6

1,2,3   5    7,9,10
```

Following this example isn't H1=3 and H2=2 and H1 isn't less than H2